# How to iterate nested json array in Python and return values for non-null elements?

Tags: arrays, json, python-2.7

New to Python (and coding!). I'm having a hard time figuring out how to iterate through a list and extract keys/values where the a specific key is not null/None. i.e "groupProps" below. Essentially what I'm after is a loop to check whether at least one element has a non-null groupProps value and to then return additional info. from that element.

i.e. print(data['myList'][1]['groupProps']['country'])

```
import json

payload = r"""{
    "myList": [{
            "groupId": "myGroup1",
            "groupProps": null
        },
        {
            "groupId": "myGroup2",
            "groupProps": {
                "country": "GB",
                "city": "London"
            }
        }
    ]
}"""

data = json.loads(payload)
```

Adding the following gets me what I'm after but not sure it's the correct way.

```
values = list(data.values())

for key,value in values:
    print(value['groupProps']['country'])
```

Edit:

Desired outcomes:

1. If at least one instance of groupProps is not null (as in above example), print the instance's nested value for "country" and associated "groupId"
2. If **all** instances of groupProps are null (as in below example), print "None"

   payload = r"""{
   "myList": [{
   "groupId": "myGroup1",
   "groupProps": null
   },
   {
   "groupId": "myGroup2",
   "groupProps": null
   }
   ]
   }"""

Comment: What do you want returned for the null cases? And do you want all items within groupProps or just country?

Comment: @QHarr 
If all items’ groupProps are null, I want to return None or similar. If at least one item’s value for groupProps is not null, return specific keys/values for that item.

Comment: I would have thought a recursive function that does an isinstance check and is None. I would hope python already has an implementation of this that deals with unknown key, value types and can specify nesting level to process to. For your current struc a not ideal way _https://pastebin.com/DcYNK6fh_